# Redirect two domains to same IP with different URL params

Tags: domain, redirect, website, domain-name

Lets say I want to have two domains pointing to two different implementations of the same web app:

> www.example.com ==> 1.1.1.1?system=one
>   www.example2.com ==> 1.1.1.1?system=two

Is this possible?
I'm using IIS over a Window 2012 machine.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled using host headers in IIS.

In the Connections pane, click the Sites node and select the site for which you want to configure a host header (ex1).
In the Actions pane, click Bindings.
In the Site Bindings dialog box, select the binding (1.1.1.1) for which you want to add a host header and then click Edit or click Add to add a new binding with a host header.
In the Host name box, type a host header for the site, such as www.example1.com.
Click OK.

For example2 add an additional host header, create a new binding with the same IP address and port, and the new host header. Repeat for each host header that you want to use this IP address and port.